# SQL SELECT from multiple tables with group

Tags: sql, join, sqlite, group-by

I have a SQLite database with following tables: hours, days, names.

Names table columns: id, name.

Days and hours tables contain following columns: id, value, time(as Unix time).

Hours table stores values for each hour from current time till current time - 3 months. Every day values that are older than 3 months are averaged to days table. So newest value from days table is 3 months old.

Is it possible to select values from a last year from both tables in one select statement grouped by days?
So i need values from days table + averaged values from hours table.

So resulting table should be like

```
id   days.value   AVG(hours.value)  day
1        13                          1
2        14                          1
1        11                          2
2        10                          2
1                        15          3
2                        17.5        3
```

Comment: Is the `names` table related to this question in any way? Why is there an output column `month` and not `day`?

Comment: is this id referenced between tables?

Comment: Well, actually names table isn't related.
Yep, my mistake. I corrected my question.

Yep, id is referenced between tables.